# WP Customer Reviews - shortcodes

Tags: plugins, review

**WP Customer Reviews Plugin**

Looking for some **shortcodes** for displaying the **review form only** / **reviews only**.

On the plugin page there is an info about shortcode (*Shortcodes available for inserting reviews and review form on any page or widget*), but I cannot find theme anywhere.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/

Have you got any experiences with the plugin? 
Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin registrer some shortcodes in wp-custom-reviews.php:

```
add_shortcode( 'WPCR_INSERT', array(&$this, 'shortcode_wpcr_insert') );
add_shortcode( 'WPCR_SHOW', array(&$this, 'shortcode_wpcr_show') );
```

Try: `[WPCR_INSERT]` and `[WPCR_SHOW]`

Comment: Great! Works. But you need to make sure to **leave unchecked "Enable WP Customer Reviews for this page"** option on the page itself. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, the plugin developer should add a description of the shortcodes on the plugin page.

Answer (score 1):

For shortcodes and their use, see the WP Admin Dashboard: Settings | WP Customer Reviews.